# What does the number at each step in debug mode mean in SWI Prolog?

Tags: debugging, prolog, swi-prolog

In SWI Prolog you can enable tracing via `trace.`. The following is an example taken from http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~kyledewey/cs162w17/debugging_prolog.html

```
[trace]  ?- X = 2, allBetween(X, 0, 3).
   Call: (7) _G1752=2 ? creep
   Exit: (7) 2=2 ? creep
   Call: (7) allBetween(2, 0, 3) ? creep
   Call: (8) 0=<3 ? creep
   Exit: (8) 0=<3 ? creep
   Call: (8) 0=2 ? creep
   Fail: (8) 0=2 ? creep
   Redo: (7) allBetween(2, 0, 3) ? creep
```

There is a number at the beginning of each step. I suppose it means something like depth, since it decreases at `Fail` and `Redo`. However, I don't know why it doesn't start from 0, but a number such as 7 or 8 (in all of my programs).

I tried to search the references on Prolog website but couldn't find it.

What does it mean exactly and why does it start from 7/8?

Comment: This is a guess but typically applies with other programs. The debugger does not start up the program being debugged directly, but an environment that host the programming being debugged. As such a few layers of calls occur during the setup and thus the number starts at 7/8. You can look at the SWI-Prolog source code on GitHub, but I don't know the exact page containing the code to see.

Comment: It's the port identifier, identifies events in Prolog abstract execution model. What's important it's the unicity of such numbers. For further interesting reading: lookup `Alan Mycroft - Hardware Byrd Boxes'.
You should find a byrdbox.ps

Answer (score 0):

From the Swi-Prolog documentation:

> The tracer shows the port, displaying the port name, the **current depth**
>   of the recursion and the goal.

Taken from: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugoverview

Also, GNU Prolog documentation has some nice explanation of Prolog debugging as well: http://gprolog.univ-paris1.fr/manual/gprolog.html#Running-and-stopping-the-debugger